# Rest API + how to handle of adding a new attribute in request payload for Post call -backward compatible vs new version

Tags: api, rest

suppose the API is
`POST /account`

and request body is

```
{Name: '',
type: '',
employment: '',
address : ''
}
```

now want to add **phone_number** as another attribute

can I make it backward compatible(minor version) by keeping this new attribute optional

OR its better to make a new version(major) so that existing clients are not impacted at all

Comment: Just use the same api and check for the presence of the new attribute. No need to create a new api version. Tip: For prototyping your REST APIs with versioning, use Wirespec (https://wirespec.dev)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the "rules" for backwards compatibility in REST are no different from in the broader category of messaging.

Assuming the semantics of the message are unchanged, and that there is a reasonable "default" interpretation of a missing optional field, then extending the message schema with a new optional value is going to be a lot easier then starting over.

You might look to HTTP itself for inspiration, in particular the design of [headers](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.2.1).  We can create new headers when it suits our purposes, with the security that components that are not familiar with our new semantics will ignore the unrecognized content.

In REST, forms are an interesting application of this idea; adding a new input control to an HTML form, with a sensible default value, is one way to offer an additional degree of control to a client that understands the new field without inhibiting the clients that don't know about it (provided, of course, those clients were designed to ignore unrecognized input controls).

A good reference on the evolution of messages: Greg Young's [Versioning in an Event Sourced System](https://leanpub.com/esversioning).